# Could anyone suggest a layout for this?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am making my first Android program.
I am making a local chat program. Both persons can type and chat on same device. The layout looks like something below.

What do you think is the best layout for this? For now I am thinking of ListActivity.
Any link to code would also be helpful.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, use a list activity where the layout consists of a relative layout which contains the listview and on top the container for the message edittext and the button.

In the listview adapter add some logic which sets the align of the text-container either to the left or the right site depending on which person wrote the text and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `RelativeLayout`. It is best solution for you.

Comment: They need to use a list view too.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using a linear layout. You can use layout weights to make the list view grow to fit the allotted space. For example:

Answer (score 0):

My soultion for this would be use a relative layout and position your items OTHERWISE use two linearlayouts one above the other and have tables inside both of them therefore.

First linearlayout will have table 4 rows to columns
Second linear layout will have 1 row 2 coumns.

Hope this helps.